# Is there any efficient way to flatten the json array

Tags: json, dataframe, json-flattener

[This is the json file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_LbrEnoYKZQSY-Fby06W_Ep6CzZI7NuO/view?usp=sharing)
My question is that how to Flatten the data per item array as needed in this file.

Properties needed :

- Tracking number
- Payment type (Prepaid/COD)
- Pickup Date Time
- Delivery Date Time
- All Out for Delivery (date/times)
- Shipment weight
- Pickup Pincode, City, State
- Drop Pincode, City, State

```
df = pd.DataFrame('json file path')

bn = pd.DataFrame(df.trackDetails.values.tolist())['trackingNumber'],['ancillaryDetails'['reasonDescription']],['datesOrTimes'['type':'ACTUAL_PICKUP', 'ACTUAL_DELIVERY', 'SHIP']],['shipmentWeight'],['statusDetail'['code':'DL'['locations'["city"],['stateOrProvinceCode']]]['shipperAddress'['city'],['stateOrProvinceCode']]]
```

But, it gives me syntax error, it is saying that-

```
SyntaxWarning: str indices must be integers or slices, not str; perhaps you missed a comma?
```

Can anyone guide me through this?

Comment: Try indenting your brackets. It will make it much easier for you to read and see the mistakes.

Comment: still getting error. Can anyone help me write the right syntax?